# How to check sub string present in a file ?

Tags: linux, string, shell, firewall

I want to write some rules in a file with a shell script . But Before adding any rule i want to check some conditions . This is my file:

**Example :**

i wrote some rule like :

```
/home/Desktop/myfile.txt

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 666 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.19.55
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 633 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.19.44
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 656 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.19.88
```

Now if the file contains same port and IP at the time of adding new rule , the script should print rule exist already . If only port present in the existing file , script should print port already in use . Otherwise , i want to print success .

that is

```
case 1 : if i add 666 port with 192.168.19.55 IP , the script should print rule already exist .
case 2 :  if i add 666 port with 192.168.66.55 IP , the script should print port already used  .
case 3 : otherwise script print success .
```

I tried to write simple shell script with arguments as IP and port:

```
#!/bin/shell
if [ $# -eq 2 ] 
then
    //How to check the above conditions with file /home/Desktop/myfile.txt ??
    //Need to add this rule to the myfile.txt 
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport $2 -j DNAT --to-destination $1
else
    echo "invalid arguments"
fi
```

Comment: Try `man grep` to learn how to use `grep`.

Comment: A questionable design, since you have to deal with endless file operations and string handling. Think about another approach: you maintain all rules inside a database which simplifies their maintenance since you can deal with data in a structured for instead of a string representation of full blown rules. And you implement an "apply" feature that dumps the contents of that database into said file, so a one way approach instead of two way handling.

Comment: So should i copy all the rules to a file and search for particular port  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` to check the contents of the file. Note that `.` is special in regular expressions, so I used parameter expansion to replace it with `\.` that matches the dot literally.

```
#!/bin/bash

config=/home/Desktop/myfile.txt

ip=$1
port=$2

if grep -q -- "--dport $port .*--to-destination ${ip//./\\.}$" "$config"; then
    echo Rule already exists. >&2
    exit 1

elif grep -q -- "--dport $port " "$config"; then
    echo Port already used. >&2
    exit 1

else
    echo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination $ip
fi
```

This is just an example. In reality, port and destination might appear in different order in the config file, so the expressions would be more complex. It might be easier to generate the file from a file that only contains the required information in a given format (i.e. two columns, destination and port).

Comment: grep -F "fixed-string" to avoid to escape metacaracters

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: Unfortunately, there's `.*`. You can pipe `grep -F` to `grep`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v port=$1 -v ip=$2 '($11 == port && $15 == ip) { print "rule already exists"  } ($11 == port && $15 != ip) { print "Port already in use" } ($11 != port && $15 != ip) { print "success";system("iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport "$2" -j DNAT --to-destination "$1) }' myfile.txt
```

With awk, we can just concentrate of the 11th space delimited piece of data for the port and the 15th for the ip address and check it against the passed parameters for port and IP printing the required text based on certain conditions and run the iptables command on success.